# When I connect to an OpenVPN server can the server access my network?

Tags: openvpn

When I connect to our work OpenVPN server I can access the servers at work. What I'm concerned about is whether work can access the machines on my network. I'm not entirely sure what to search for but I've found posts where people desire this behaviour.

What I'd like is to know what setting to put in my client.ovpn file to forcibly disable it.

I've got the following client config

```
route-nopull
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 # internal work network
```

By not explicitly specifying a route to my network is it disabled or can the server add one?